# XSLT replace conditional logic with matching rules

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet that is invoking templates in the wrong order. Rather than rendering paragraphs and tables in the order in which they appear, it renders all the paragraphs, followed by all the tables. I'm guessing that this problem would be resolved by replacing conditional logic with pattern matching, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

The full XSLT is here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="richtext">
        <xsl:if test="par">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="par" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="table">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="table" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="richtext" mode="par">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="par[run[normalize-space()]]" group-adjacent="if (@def) then @def else preceding-sibling::par[run[normalize-space()]][@def][1]/@def">
            <xsl:variable name="listType" select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::pardef]/@list" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$listType = 'bullet'">    
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="list"/>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="para" />   
                </xsl:otherwise>     
            </xsl:choose>   
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="richtext" mode="table">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="table/tablerow">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tablecell">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates />
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par" mode="list">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
        </li>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par" mode="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
        </p>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
         <xsl:value-of select="text()" separator=""/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <item name="Some richtext">
        <richtext>
            <pardef/>
            <par def="20">
                <run>This is a </run>
                <run>paragraph.</run>
            </par>
            <table>
                <tablerow>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="43"><run>This is a table</run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="44"><run>This is some data</run></par></tablecell>
                </tablerow>
            </table>
            <pardef id="21" list="bullet"/>
            <par def="21">
                <run>This is a </run>
                <run>bullet point.</run>
            </par>
            <table>
                <tablerow>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="43"><run>This is another table</run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="44"><run>This is some data</run></par></tablecell>
                </tablerow>
            </table>
        </richtext>
    </item>
</document>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
  <body>
     <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
     <table border="1">
        <tr>
           <td>This is a table</td>
           <td>This is some data</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <ul>
        <li>This is a bullet point.</li>
     </ul>
     <table border="1">
           <tr>
              <td>This is another table</td>
              <td>This is some data</td>
           </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be honest with you, this is not a code writing service. Your last **9!** questions are on the same topic. It always solves the given problem, but not your project in summary. Learn XSLT to understand the given solutions, not only copy-paste them. I think a moderator needs to investigate.

Comment: The problem is not actually with your conditional logic, but how the template with mode "par" works. It would probably help if you editted your question to show this template, and the one for "table" too (I know it is in a previous question, but questions should really be self-contained). Thank you.

Comment: Hi @uL I'm actually not a newbie -- I used XSLT extensively in 2003-2005 and then again a couple of years ago -- but I get rusty because I don't do this all the time. It may not be apparent, but I have been studying the answers to try to understand them. Thanks to everyone for bearing with me while I try to get up to speed.

Comment: @b00kgrrl I don't see why you need conditional logic here at all. Just apply templates to `par` and to `table` and have a template to handle each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a lot of your problems stem from trying to use @mode to do the job of @match.  A good rule of thumb is to avoid @mode unless you are likely to process the same node(s) or node type more than once, or want to do different things at different times.

As @michael.hor257k says, you're better off letting apply templates do the logic selection for you.

Also your tests are a bit wonky, looking to see if there is any table/par child of richtext, rather than what the current context node is (which is what apply-templates already does for you): both xsl:if statements there will be true for your example.

Here is some XSLT that will create what you want from your input (in XHTML rather than HTML): I do end up using a mode to differentiate between lists and normal paragraphs, but this obeys the rule of thumb above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:local="http://example.com/local" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs local"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xhtml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="pars" match="par" use="preceding-sibling::pardef[1]/generate-id()"/>

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <html>
      <head/>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- I want to handle par using modes, so I deliberately remove any output in the default mode.  We'll make an exception for par in table later. -->
  <xsl:template match="par"/>

  <xsl:template match="pardef[not(@list)]">
    <!-- I'm using a key() function here just to easily return the par elements that follow this pardef
      - see the xsl:key definition above.  You could also try using @id and @def e.g. 
      <key name="pars" match="par" use="@def"/>
      and key('pars', @id) - although the first @id in your example seems to be missing!
    -->

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pars', generate-id())" mode="p"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pardef[@list]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pars', generate-id())" mode="li"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="par" mode="p">
    <p>
      <!-- Any further elements don't need mode handling, so we'll return to the default mode -->
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#default"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="par" mode="li">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#default"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tablerow">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tablecell/par">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If anyone can tell me why I had to use generate-id() instead of just . in the key function and definition, I'd like to know - I think it may be a bug in my Saxon (9.6.0.7).

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: @yamahito, if you had used `use="."` in the key definition then the string value of the empty `<pardef/>` would have been used and would have been the same value, the empty string, for all empty `pardef` elements. You haven't said which result you got but I don't think using the same value for several `pardef` elements would work with your algorithm.

Comment: Ah, it's the string value.  For some reason I misremembered that something equivalent to the 'is' comparator would be used in 2.  Always something new to learn!